# Problem getting current post tags to show in a widget

Tags: loop, widgets, tags

I have tried tons of examples and suggestion on this topic but I can not get them to work.

What I am trying to do is display the tags associated with the current post in a widget.

I have built the widget and the widget works fine but I can not write the code to query the posts tags and display them.

I understand the basics that needs to be done to get post meta from outside the loop but I can not pull the exact code together.

Can someone start me off by showing me a piece of code to get the current post tags and display them from outside the loop? I can handle making the output look fine.